# Using $(this) does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I am trying to get a script running that adds some events to a class.
I want these events only to be added to one specific DIV among this class. I am using pep.js:

```
 $( ".drag" ).pep({
start: function() {
        $(".drag").addClass('color');
        $('.drag').next(".text").fadeIn("slow");
        $(".text-video").fadeOut("fast");

    },
stop: function() {
        $('.drag').removeClass('color');
        $('.drag').next(".text").fadeOut("slow");
    }

  });
```

This works, but it triggers all .drag items at once… And I want only the one I am dragging to have added all the events.

I tried to write it with:

```
$(".drag", this).addClass('color');
```

or:

```
$(this).addClass('color');
```

or:

```
$(this.element).addClass('color');
```

But it all didn't work.
Does someone have an idea?

**UPDATE:**

I made a JSFiddle that hopefully explains my problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/ke6d5r1h/

As you see, the .color class for example is not only added to the DIV that is dragged, but also to the other. This is what I want to change.

Comment: What does `console.log(this)` show you?

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: In what way does it not work? Does it give you a specific error message? Please read this article on how to ask a question on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I made a JS Fiddle with the Problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `console.log(arguments)` in the event handlers, I was able to determine that the handlers are passed two arguments: the event object, and an object containing context. The context has a property `$el`, which is a jQuery object for the event target.

```
start: function(e,a) {
    a.$el.addClass('color');
    a.$el.next(".text").fadeIn("slow");
    $(".text-video").fadeOut("fast"); 
},
```

https://jsfiddle.net/85tffqhL/

`e.target` would also give you a reference to the element.

Comment: THIS WORKS PERFECT!!! Thank you so much! Ok that is new for me, I am a total rookie in JQuery… Thank you for your help!!!